# Assign user to a default account in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

Using Thunderbird 45.8.0. I have two email accounts, let us call them `work@gmail.com` and `play@gmail.com`. Say I have two contacts:

- `The Boss`
- `Poker Friend`

If I have the `play@gmail.com` account selected in the left-hand pane and start writing a new email to `The Boss`, the `play@gmail.com` account is selected and I must change the account to `work@gmail.com` before sending the email. This is an accident waiting to happen.

Ideally Thunderbird would switch to `work@gmail.com` when I selected myfirst contact (`The Boss`).

Is it possible to assign a default account to contacts?

Looking through all the Address Book options I cannot see a way to do this. This gets tricky for multiple users, but the software would only have to switch account for the first contact added (or maybe the option would be to switch, if required, as each new contact is added) to reduce most accidents.